# vCenter Server Appliance SSO Active Directory Sync Interval

Tags: vmware-vcenter

I replaced our Windows-based vCenter 5.1 server with the 5.5 Linux-based appliance a few months ago and am very happy with it. However one thing that's been puzzling me since I deployed it is how to speed up the synchronization of group membership from Active Directory. Sometimes it takes days to pick up that the permissions of a user has changed!

Does anyone know either how to change the interval or force an update?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't found this documented anywhere. But the secret seems to be to log into the console as root via SSH and running "service vmdird restart".

My guesswork was aided by this VMWare KB article listing what each service is:
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2054085